# Filter Dataframes into a csv via python

Tags: python, api, csv, formatting

I'm programming something via python, to grab data from a api and export that to a csv. I got some help here and it worked. Now i'm at a point where i don't know how to solve that.

The Code looks like that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = "https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article"
r = requests.get('https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article')

headers = {
'Accept': "application/json",
'Content-Type': "application/json",
'Authorization': "Bearer xxx"
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

dic = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df.to_csv('stock.csv', index=False, sep="\t")
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json(), index=[0])
```

And the export looks like that
[image]

And i want the export to look like that

[image]

So that means as a example "intern_name" should listed as "Productname" with the name of the Product down below.

Thank u for the time and infos. I really can't pass this point here (learning python btw)

Comment: What does the actual `DataFrame` look like?

Comment: Hei! It looks like that `'[{"id":34,"user_id":1,"article_type_id":1,"contact_id":null,"deliverer_code":"","deliverer_name":"","deliverer_description":"","intern_code":"TEXLINE-SOLD","intern_name":"TEXLINE Sold out","intern_description":"","purchase_price":"0.900000","sale_price":"2.450000","purchase_total":null,"sale_total":null,"currency_id":1,"`@AaronKeesing

Comment: If you print the `df` `DataFrame`, it should be nicely formatted as a table with aligned columns and rows, so if it doesn't appear like that, it means that it's not reading in the dict properly, and would explain why it's not outputting how you expect. What you've written there is just a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you have an idea how I can implement this differently to make this work? That would help me and I would learn something new

Comment: What does the `stock.csv` file look like in a text editor? Does it have tabs?

Comment: And what is the value of the JSON dict that you get?

Comment: In a texteditor, the stock.csv looks pretty good. It good tabs. And i made in Excel now a import from "text to csv" and it got all tabs and down below the right data. So i need to export that right (i think, excel formatted it wrong at the start), filter just a few dataframes like "id" and "contact_id" with the values down below and name them different like "id = Productnumber"

Comment: I've added an answer regarding the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765997/filter-dataframes-into-a-csv-via-python#comment112771091_63765997) it looks like the output CSV is formatted correctly, but the column names need to change. One way to do that is to simply assign to the `columns` property of the `DataFrame` while mapping each name to a new name:

```py
column_map = {'id': 'Productnumber', ...}

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: column_map.get(x, x))
```

Here, the `get(x, x)` is used to either return the corresponding value, or just the name if the name isn't in the dict.

**EDIT:** In order to select just a subset of the columns you can index the `DataFrame` using a list after you've mapped the columns:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: column_map.get(x, x))
df = df[column_map.values()]
```

Comment: Hei, thank u for your support btw. I really preshade it. So  i mapped the columns and add `df = df[column_map.values()]`. That's the output `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1298, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['ProductKey', 'QuantityOnStock', 'MinimumOrderQuantity'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"` i guess i just did it wrong. Have u me an example how the code would look like? just if u got time :)

Comment: Are you sure you selected the columns *after* you mapped them? Because it should just work. If you select the columns before you would need to do `df = df[column_map.keys()]` and *then* map.

Comment: I mapped them `column_map = {'id': 'ProductKey', 'stock_available_nr': 'QuantityOnStock', 'stock_min_nr': 'MinimumOrderQuantity'}` (and the export is right) and after that i use `df = df[column_map.values()]`

Comment: I've updated my code so it's a bit clearer, but if it's still not working then I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I learned a lot from u. Thank u for the time. I got one last question! Everything works and now the output are great. But it is possible to filter the output? Like i got the output in the csv with `
MNMBB0      68
MNMBB      472
MNMBB01-PG      73
SPBG-11 166
SP-10   459
SP-09   0
SP-08   1037
` but i just need the infos with "MNM" in the CSV. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to extract just some info from string values in a column, you can map the values similarly to how you mapped the column names, e.g. `df['<column name>'] = df['<column name>'].map(lambda x: ...)`. You can use regular expressions from the Python `re` module for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221135/discussion-between-sleepersimulant-and-aaron-keesing).

Answer (score 0):

Mate, thank u so much.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = "https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article"
r = requests.get('https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article')
headers = {
'Accept': "application/json",
'Content-Type': "application/json",
'Authorization': "Bearer"
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

# Grab Data and export to csv
dic = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
column_map = {'id': 'ProductKey', 'stock_available_nr': 'QuantityOnStock',             
'stock_min_nr': 'MinimumOrderQuantity'}
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: column_map.get(x, x))
df.to_csv('yeet.csv', index=False, sep="\t")

# CSV to FTP-Server
```

That's the code right now. It's possble just to export the Values where i used up there? Like just "id", "stockavailable_nr" and "stock_min_nr"?